# How to override urlpattern in web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC project incorporating Tiles.

Here is the current urlPattern in the web.xml.

`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

In the spring configuration file, currently the only view resolver is.

`<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver"
        p:basename="views" />`

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
    p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
```

In my controller, the only way the request mapping works is if I enter in /sample.html which routs to the proper controller. What I need to do is have the current view /sample to map to the proper controller. Is there a way to do this. Would internalviewresolver or an entry change in the views.properties file be the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to change the servlet url-pattern. Map it to `/`